# How to initialize a local variable in its declaration in Eiffel?

Tags: variables, eiffel

I tried to do this:

```
local
    condition: BOOLEAN
    condition := true
do
```

And something like this:

```
local
    condition: BOOLEAN := true
do
```

Obviously neither work, but I need to initialize a variable inside the declaration because I don't want the variable to re-initialize if a retry instruction is executed.
I looked in Eiffel's oficial documentation and in tutorial but they always intitialize variables in the body of the operation.

Answer (score 8):

Every variable is initialised in Eiffel, so in local they all get their default value, which is false for BOOLEAN.

Note that for a retry the variables are not initialised to their default again, so you can use that with:

```
test
  local
    retrying: BOOLEAN
  do
    if retrying then
      do_something_else
    else
      retrying := true
      first_try
    end;
  rescue
    handle_error
    retry
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
local
condition: BOOLEAN = true
do
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local
   condition: BOOLEAN
do
   condition := True
   ...
```